# Hit de engajamento do Google Analytics. Posso criar um "automático"?

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

Para quem não sabe, para calcular o "tempo médio da sessão" de um usuário, o Google Analytics procede da seguinte forma: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=pt-BR

Para esclarecer o que é um "hit de engajamento": http://cutroni.com/blog/2012/02/29/understanding-google-analytics-time-calculations/

Eu tenho um app pra Android que possui 2 telas: a primeira é inicial (onde o usuário escolhe qual conteúdo irá ver), a segunda possui o conteúdo escolhido. Na tela inicial, o usuário gasta cerca de 5 segundos para selecionar o conteúdo que irá ver, na segunda tela, por se tratar do conteúdo em si, o usuário gasta cerca de 30 segundos. Então, o tempo total da sessão do usuário deveria ser de 35 segundos, mas, infelizmente, como a segunda tela não possui um "hit de engajamento", os 30 segundos gastos nela são "perdidos". Isso é muito ruim para as estatísticas do meu aplicativo.

Eu estava imaginando se poderia criar um evento na segunda tela que dispara automaticamente a cada 5 segundos para "forçar" um hit de engajamento e obter a duração real da sessão do usuário. Talvez um disparo automático de algum dado ou hit para o analytics através do event tracker, não sei.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Alguma ideia para contornar essa falha?

Entrei em contato com o suporte do Google, mas não conseguiram me dar respostas satisfatórias.

Obrigado.

Comment: Minha sugestão para dar a continuidade no cálculo do engajamento seria disparar eventos de **PageView** durante o ciclo de vida da `Activity`. Acredito que você já faça isso durante o `onCreate`, mas se você fizer no `onPause` e `onResume` por exemplo (em vez do `onCreate`)?. Se o usuário deixar seu aplicativo, ele irá gerar um registro dessa saída. Agora o único problema é se **PageView's** "duplicados" não irão causar problemas, porque ele sempre terá no mínimo 2 para cada `Activity`.

Comment: @Wakim Boa ideia, olhei agora, a documentação pede pra adicionar eventos no onCreate e no onStop (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/#tracking-methods). Quando o onStop ocorre, o hit disparado deve ser de engajamento. Meu tempo de sessão do GA deve estar correto então. A definição que dão pra esse "hit de engajamento" que complica o entendimento de tudo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Eu nunca utilizei o Google Analytics em apps do Android, mas e se você acompanhar o scroll do usuário, enviando um evento ao Analytics a cada determinado momento?

Por exemplo, aos 25% depois aos 50%, 75% e por fim, 100%.

O único problema é que a taxa de rejeição irá cair absurdamente, então o ideal seria não enviar como um hit de usuário.

Como disse, por ser app de Android, não posso lhe dar 100% de certeza em relação a implantação, mas qualquer coisa pode perguntar.

Comment: Talvez seja uma saída. Não entendi porque a taxa de rejeição cairia... E vc sabe me dizer se hit de engajamento só conta se o usuário necessariamente **clicar** em alguma coisa? Se eu criar um método pra voltar pra página anterior em 5 segundos (por exemplo), valeria como um hit de engajamento?

Comment: A taxa de rejeição cai pq se mesmo o usuário entrar, rolar o scroll e sair, sem nem ler, seria considerado interação, portanto não houve rejeição.. Por isso disse para utilizar esse método enviando com não intenção.

Comment: Respondendo a segunda pergunta,  Page view é considerado hit, portanto novamente a taxa de rejeição cairia, já que o usuário teria visto duas páginas (mesmo sem ele querer)

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda, vou aguardar mais respostas (se houver né). Vou testar as ideias que vc me deu.(obs: não tenho reputação suficiente pra marcar sua resposta como útil)